# Prove that there is no homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ ont0 $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Prove that there is no homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ ont0 $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

My idea for the proof : Let $\phi$ be such homomorphism. Since Ker $\phi$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ , then i must find all possible subgroups of it and then prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2})/$Ker$\:\phi $ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ where Ker $\phi$ can be any of the subgroup. To prove it isnt isomorphic is by finding elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ that has order such that no elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ have that order.

Is there any better way..?

Comment: Both groups have the same order. So if you can show that a homomorphism must have nontrivial kernel, you have shown that there is no homomorphism onto.

Comment: You have been given a perfectly satisfactory answer below. A way of rephrasing your question is, you are looking for an invariant (a property that is preserved by isomorphism) that takes different values for the two groups. In this case the invariant is the exponent, for the first group it is 8, for the second it is 4 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_group

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A surjective function between two finite sets of the same cardinality is also injective, so your homomorphism would be an isomorphism. This is not possible, because the first group has an element of order $8$ and the second one doesn't.